# Can I change my.inf in OpenShift without root access?

Tags: mysql, openshift, root, root-access

I want to sync a local database with *OpenShift MySQL*, but I can't change `my.inf` because I don't have root access. Is it possible to get root access on *OpenShift*?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are interested in `my.cnf`. If you ssh into your gear (`rhc ssh <yourApp>`) and check the file (`~/mysql/conf/my.cnf`), you will see that it's owned by you, the root access is not needed.

However, if you check the beginning of the file, you will see:

```
# WARNING: Changes to this file will be lost on every restart/upgrade.  Configurable values can be set with environment variables through rhc env set...
#
# Ex: rhc env set OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_LOWER_CASE_TABLE_NAMES=1 -a myapp && rhc cartridge restart -c mysql-5.5 -a myapp
#
# Configurable Values:
# lower_case_table_names -> OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_LOWER_CASE_TABLE_NAMES
# default-storage-engine -> OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DEFAULT_STORAGE_ENGINE
# max_connections -> OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_MAX_CONNECTIONS
# ft_min_word_len -> OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_FT_MIN_WORD_LEN
# ft_max_word_len -> OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_FT_MAX_WORD_LEN
```

Which should answer your question on what is configurable and how to do it.

Comment: Hi Jiri,
you mean I can modify my.cnf with rhc ssh. Is it?
And can I add variable "server_id" in config file as configurable values ?

Comment: Yes and no. You can edit the file, but as noted in the file itself, the only persisting configuration changes would be those made using environment variables using `rhc env set`. The `server_id` is not among those 5 environment variables listed there.

Comment: I want to replicate local db with openshift mysql. So I have to make changes in the my.cnf. Is there any way to get root access?

Comment: I'm afraid that root access to gears is not available.